# error 500 in laravel project using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-image

I created a Laravel project with Decker, but when I run the project on port 0.0.0.0:8080
, it returns the error.

**0.0.0.0 is currently unable to handle this request.**

**HTTP ERROR 500**

error text in laravel.log file :

```
#23 /home/amir/Projects/laravel/school/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http
```

my operating system : ubuntu 16.04

my laravel version : 5

Comment: A 500 Internal Server Error means that there's a fatal error somewhere. Check your logs. Without any specific information on the code or any errors, we can't really help.

Comment: the question is edited .

Comment: Is your web server even configured for port 8080? And pointing to `/public/` directory?

Comment: post the piece of docker-compose.yml that you created the docker image for laravel with. What did you add in your hosts file? in your laravel.log file should be more than just that line of code. There's no errors in there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows. I did the following steps:

1. Open `.env` file in your project
2. Delete `APP_KEY` code (**Just Code**)
3. Go in terminal and type `php artisan key:generate`
4. You can see the new `APP_KEY` code

Now you can Run Your Project .